# What song is "I am from New York, I am from New York" in Brooklyn Nine Nine

Tags: soundtrack, brooklyn-nine-nine

```
Series: Brooklyn nine nine
Season: 3
Episode: 23
Episode Title: Greg and Larry
```

Scenario: In the episode  with Bob Anderson, when the whole 99 squad comes out of hospital, they decide to disguise as hospital staff and there is a song played in the background

Link to the video: [Season 3 Episode 23](https://youtu.be/WVbw_B8jmSQ?t=340)

```
"I' ffam New York I 'ffam, New York. I 'ffam I 'ffam New York I' ffam New York".
```

Any idea what the original song is? Or is it edited/sped up from some existing/New song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_and_Larry) for the episode in question shows the featured music in the sidebar on the right of the page.

The song listed is: "New York" by Ja Rule featuring Fat Joe and Jadakiss. You can listen to the [song on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kf4EoRnaEM).

It seems like it's an edited/remixed version of the song